# Error while executing powershell script to add two keys in appSettings

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, web-config, web.config-transform

I want to add two keys value in appSetting in Sharepoint web.config file.

I found a good example modifying blobcache attribute using following link,

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/14/use-powershell-to-script-changes-to-the-sharepoint-web-config-file.aspx

and also following link where I can add new keys.

http://farhanfaiz.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/sharepoint-2010-powershell-script-to-add-in-web-config/

And here is my code to add two keys in Appsetting.

```
function AddAppSettingKey { 

param( 

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, Position=0)] 

    [Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPWebApplicationPipeBind] 

    $WebApplication 


) 

process { 

    Write-Host "Modification starts..." -ForegroundColor Green
    $WebApp = $WebApplication.Read() 
    Write-Host $WebApp

    $configMod1 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
    $configMod1.Path = "configuration/appSettings"
    $configMod1.Name =  "add[@name='key']"
    $configMod1.Value = "<add key= 'RedirectToPage' value='Main.aspx' />"
    $configMod1.Sequence = 0
    $configMod1.Type = 1 
    $configMod1.Owner = "AppSettingMod"

    $configMod2 = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebConfigModification
    $configMod2.Path = "configuration/appSettings" 
    $configMod2.Name =  "add[@name='key']"
    $configMod2.Value = "<add key= 'isProd' value='false' />"
    $configMod2.Sequence = 0
    $configMod2.Type = 1 
    $configMod2.Owner = "AppSettingMod" 

    $WebApp.WebConfigModifications.Add($configMod1)
    $WebApp.WebConfigModifications.Add($configMod2)  
    $WebApp.Update() 
    $WebApp.Parent.ApplyWebConfigModifications()

     Write-Host "Done......" -ForegroundColor Cyan

    }

}
```

But my problem is when I execute code, I get following error:

```
Exception calling "ApplyWebConfigModifications" with "0" argument(s): "'/' is a
n unexpected token.
```

Any input will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I see "`.Type = 1`" which is `SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureAttribute`, while you should use  `SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode(0)`, I suppose.

Change to "`.Type = 0`" and try again.